# Make popups appear before forceful quit JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, forceclose

So I have been working on a basic text editor for practicing with javaFX.
I want to make it so that when I do a force quit using the task manager (On Mac and Windows) or anything along those lines a box appears asking if you want to save. I have got this working normally but not with the force quit. I have been experimenting with shutdown hooks and I am wondering if I can do something there to make it work.

`Platform.exit();` from a different thread does not work :(

Example

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class num1 extends Application{
public static void main(String[]args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage mainStage) throws Exception {
    mainStage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
        System.out.print("QUIT");
    });
    mainStage.show();
}
}
```

Quitting this using the force quit on mac or the task manager on windows will not trigger the action

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure you can interrupt a force quit.  If you try this with native apps they also close without a prompt - I tried with word and it just goes away as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for.

```
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(e->{  //stage is your Stage object
            myPopupFunction(); // your popup function
            e.consume(); // consume the event to not propagate further
        });
```

Comment: Nope. That is only soft quit. NOT force quit

Comment: Maybe I do not understand what you are referring to, but I am pretty sure that right click->close, or alt+F4 are triggering this, and consuming the event will not close the app. Are you 100% that this is not what you need?

Comment: Yes. I Will update this question with a code snippet

Comment: Oooh. Oky got it. Yes you are right, will not be triggered. No idea how to solve your issue though ...

Comment: Please post your solution when you find something. I am very curious as well ^_^